# Updating Draggable Marker Position Values

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to update markers positions (lat and long) after dragging the Markers at this <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/nnw39/2/)**</kbd>. As you can see I able to grab the Markers's Positions(lat long) but when I replace a marker the captured value is not updating!

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.038003,125.736294);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var cnt = 0;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            title: "Camp Num: " + ++cnt
        });
           $('#myTable tbody:eq(1)').append('<tr class="child"><td>'+ marker.title +'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lat()+'</td><td>'+ marker.position.lng()+'</td></tr>');
    });

});
```

Can you please let me know how I can update them

Comment: Do you mean when you drag the marker, you want to show new values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to update the new position of marker after drag?, If yes, then we need to do following:

- Add event listener for each added marker. For this, I am adding listener for `dragend`.
- Assign 'id' to marker and when `<td>` is created on click, we assign to it; so that later we can update the row when marker is dragged.
- If we click on map, then marker is added, if marker is dragged, it is updated.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gyuv3/)